# How can I transform an object to be grouped by object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object which also contains arrays and objects and which is currently grouped by "category"

```
data = {
  vehicles: [
    {
      name: "Team1",
      cars: [
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "cars"
        },
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "cars"
        }
      ],
      bike: [
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "bike"
        }
      ],
      scooter: [
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "scooter"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Team2",
      cars: [
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "cars"
        },
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "cars"
        }
      ],
      bike: [
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "bike"
        }
      ],
      scooter: [
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "scooter"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

I used this line of code to groupby category but

```
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
var data = groupBy(data, "category");
```

Since I have the object "data" now I want to perfrom further transformation
My question is it possible to groupby two categories so the output looks like this

```
data = {
  vehicles: [
    {
      name: "Team1",
      cars: [
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "cars"
        },
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "cars"
        }
      ],
      bike_scooter: [
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "bike"
        },
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "scooter"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Team2",
      cars: [
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "cars"
        },
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "cars"
        }
      ],
      bike_scooter: [
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "bike"
        },
        {
          multiple: 0.5,
          category: "scooter"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with `two` reduce methods one to build vehicles array and other one to group in each object by provided array of keys.

```js
const data = {"vehicles":[{"name":"Team1","cars":[{"multiple":0.5,"category":"cars"},{"multiple":0.5,"category":"cars"}],"bike":[{"multiple":0.5,"category":"bike"}],"scooter":[{"multiple":0.5,"category":"scooter"}]},{"name":"Team2","cars":[{"multiple":0.5,"category":"cars"},{"multiple":0.5,"category":"cars"}],"bike":[{"multiple":0.5,"category":"bike"}],"scooter":[{"multiple":0.5,"category":"scooter"}]}]};

function groupBy(data, keys) {
  return data.vehicles.reduce((r, {name,...rest}) => {
    const obj = Object.entries(rest).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
      if (keys.includes(k)) {
        const key = keys.join('_');
        if (!a[key]) a[key] = [...v];
        else a[key].push(...v);
      } else a[k] = [...v]
      return a
    }, {name})

    r.vehicles.push(obj)
    return r;
  }, {
    vehicles: []
  })
}

console.log(groupBy(data, ['bike', 'scooter']))
console.log(groupBy(data, ['bike', 'cars']))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but why are the team names missing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
data.vehicles.map(obj => {
  obj.bike_scooter = [];
  obj.bike_scooter.push(...obj.bike);
  obj.bike_scooter.push(...obj.scooter);
  delete obj.bike;
  delete obj.scooter;
});
console.log(data);
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for why this works?

Comment: @economy I looped through each object in vehicles and created a property bike_scooter on that object. I pushed bike and scooter property values to newly created bike_scooter property. Then I deleted bike and scooter properties from the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, which will update data in place

```
let groupBy = ['bike','scooter'];
data.vehicles.forEach((vehicle) => {
    const resultKey = groupBy.join('_');
    vehicle[resultKey] = [];
    groupBy.forEach((by) => {
        vehicle[resultKey] = vehicle[resultKey].concat(vehicle[by]);
        delete vehicle[by]; 
    });
});
```